# lldb debug Chromium not showing variable correct

Tags: debugging, chromium, lldb

Guys, I have successfully built a debug version of Chromium on OS X Mavericks‎ 10.9.2 by following this [instruction](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/Clang) with `ninja -C out/Debug chrome`.

The question is when I debugging(using lldb) into the Chromium, I cannot show all of the variable's value in the debugger:

[image: screenshot]

The variable `isolate` is showing correct, but not the `element_size`. How can I let the debugger know where to find the `element_size` and others? Is this something about global and local variable? Thanks!

Comment: I found that in order to Control Size of Debug Information,there is three options for that: -g0\-gline-tables-only\-g,the default is -gline-tables-only(more details [http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-size-of-debug-information])I have changed the **-gline-tables-only** to **-g** which means generating complete debug info but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Check your optimization settings.  If you are not building -O0 it may be that the compiler has figured out it doesn't need this variable, and so the debugger's not going to be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks, I got the main idea,but it doesn't work yet.